# Book recommendation on maximum likelihood estimation with proofs in general settings

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, soft-question, book-recommendation, maximum-likelihood

I am looking for a book (or serious notes) that contains a chapter on maximum likelihood estimation with all proofs on consistency, functional invariance, efficiency, second-order efficiency after correction for bias... preferably from a measure theoretic point of view. Any recommendation ?

Comment: You can check out *Elements of Large-Sample Theory* by Lehmann or *Mathematical Statistics* by Shao.